# Declare multiple String variables and initialize them to all to null at once

Tags: java

I want to declare all of them `null`. Am I doing someting wrong or is this the right method?

```
String a = null, b = null, c = null, d = null;
```

(Is there any more compact syntax for doing this?)

Comment: Try it out, then you see. If it compiles, then it's correct.

Comment: @it works but cant i do it at once insted of writing null in front of ech varable?

Comment: *Note* - they are not set to `null` *at one time*, like: *simultaneously*. It is still a sequence of assign operations (useless operations, btw, in this special example)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yep. That's the way to do it.

You could also do

```
String a, b, c, d;
a = b = c = d = null;
```

The line below however won't compile:

```
String a = b = c = d = null;  // illegal
```

(Note that if these are member variables, they will be initialized to `null` automatically.)

Answer (score 9):

You may want something like this:

```
String a, b, c, d = a = b = c = null;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're setting it to *null*,

```
String a, b, c, d;
```

would be enough as the declaration would set it to null by default.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17013823/2434565) thread for further explanation.

Otherwise if you're setting `a, b, c, d` to some value, you would have to use the solutions mentioned above.

Comment: You will be getting this compilation error: The local variable a may not have been initialized.

Answer (score 2):

That's perfectly valid. I suppose a slightly shorter way of doing it is:

```
String a, b, c, d;
a = b = c = d = null;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's how o do it.

**However**, if you find yourself writing that sort of construct often in might be a sign that you are declaring a variable too early, before you know what value to put in it:

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=126

**Edit:** You might alsdo want to look at this:

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=14